# Write hebrew with log4net

Tags: log4net, hebrew

I write mixed Hebrew and English characters to a file using log4net but instead of Hebrew i see question marks.

I've tried setting Application's and Thread's culture info to 'he-IL' but it doesn't seem to help.

Does log4net support Hebrew characters? If so, how can i make it work?
Thanks

Edit:
This is my config section:

```
<appender name="ErrorsFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <param name="File" value="c:\\taskman\\service.log"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
  <datePattern value="'service.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d;%m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

The hebrew text comes from the DB which is an SQL server 2005.

Comment: What are you viewing the output in? Could it be you're viewing the result with a font that doesn't support your character set?

Comment: I've tried Notepad, EditPlus and VS2010, all show the same.

Comment: Can you add your log4net configuration section. Where are you taking the values form? DB? Web page?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you manage to display Hebrew yet?

Comment: Mr Mush, r u Eyal Mush?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line to your `app.config` file, in the `appender` section:

```
<encoding value="windows-1255" />
```

Answer (score 2):

After I tried adding the `windows-1255` to the encoding value I still had issue with Hebrew text.

I ended up adding :
`<encoding value="utf-8" />`

And it worked only in **UTF-8** mode

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue here.
I have configured log4net with the following settings:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="giscraweler.txt" />
      <encoding value="windows-1255" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

I saw the font good in the Visual studio debug window, But when i opened the log file with Notepad++ - The text was not right, i saw weird characters.

How to fix ? Set up your "*character sets*" as first comment suggested.
I selected character sets windows-1255 and now i see the hebrew fonts.